# Transform a 3D array into a matrix in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to transform a 3D array into a matrix. I want the third dimension of the array to form the first row in the matrix, and this third dimension should be read by row (i.e., row 1, then row 2 etc... of dimension 3 should make up the first row of the matrix). I've given an example below, where the array has dimensions of 4, 3, and 5, and the resulting matrix has 5 rows and 12 columns. I have a solution below that achieves what I want, but it seems very cumbersome for large arrays (it first creates vectors from the elements of the array (by row), and then rbinds these to form the matrix). Is there a more elegant way to do this? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
dat <- array( rnorm(60), dim=c(4, 3, 5) )   

results <- list(1:5)            
for (i in 1:5) {  
    vec <- c( t(dat[, , i]) )  
    results[[i]] <- vec  
    }

datNew <- rbind( results[[1]], results[[2]], results[[3]], results[[4]], results[[5]] )
```

Comment: You should change the formulation. You probably mean by  "first element" of an array the matrix printed when the array is printed. Those matrixes are the elements of the  _3rd_  dimension of the array. From your example I see that you just want to flatten first two dimensions. My answer below gives you what you want.

Comment: Thanks VitoshKa for pointing that out - I edited the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `aperm`

```
X <- aperm(dat,c(3,2,1))
dim(X)<- c(5, 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

One line answer:

```
t(apply(dat,3,"c"))
```